# How to pass data from a step to another programmatically in Rundeck?

Tags: java, plugins, rundeck

Is it possible to pass data in Java Rundeck plugin, from a custom step to another?

To simplify my case, I have two NodeStepPlugins.

> 1. class GeneratorPlugin implements NodeStepPlugin{...}
> 2. class ConsumerPlugin implements NodeStepPlugin{...}

GeneratorPlugin generates a certain amount of variables.
ConsumerPlugin needs to access those variables to do further actions.

I was thinking of a way of passing those variables though datacontext, shared context, etc but it seems that any value I add, is not propagated to the ConsumerPlugin.

```
context.getExecutionContext().getSharedDataContext()
```

I appreciate any ideas that can solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate? What are you trying to do? Could you post your code or example to understand the problem and your goal?

Comment: sure, my bad, please check my updated description

Comment: Not sure about your goal, but that's already possible using data passing, take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/passing-variables.html#passing-data-between-steps (even between jobs). Hope it helps!

Comment: It might work, but it is far from ideal to the problem Im trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be possible by placing the values in:

```
context.getExecutionContext().getPrivateDataContext()
```